# checking a radio button from it's name as a string

Tags: vb.net, loops, controls

So let's say I have 5 radio buttons on my form.

In my code, I want to check RadioButton3.
I have "RadioButton3" stored in a string variable (RadName)

I can already loop through the controls on the form. How do I go about checking (and actually having the radio button filled in), RadioButton3 when the loop gets to it?

```
   For Each RadioButtn As Control In Me.gbWriteXML.Controls
        If (TypeOf RadioButtn Is RadioButton) Then
           ---code here for checking the radio button---
        End If
    Next
```

The .gbWriteXML is a groupbox. Just to avoid any confusion.  I was thinking something like:

```
If RadioButtn.Name = RadName Then
      RadName.Checked = True (or .PerformClick for that button)
End If
```

How can I actually get the control associated with the RadName string, via the control's name?
I need this code to be able to take a radiobutton's name as string hardcoded or entered into the program at runtime, loop until it find the radiobutton with a matching name, then actually taking that radiobutton control, and checking it so it's filled in blue.

Comment: Change `RadName.Checked = True` to `RadioButtn.Checked = True`. Both `Name` and `Checked` are just properties of the RadioButtn object here. Visual Studio creates variables for each object you put on the Form in the Designer and just names the variables the same as the `Name` property. That's why you can access them in your code directly with their name as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop.  Just search for it with `Controls.Find()` like this:

```
    Dim RadName As String = "RadioButton3"
    Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(RadName, True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is RadioButton Then
        Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(matches(0), RadioButton)
        rb.Checked = True
    End If
```